# Moved the file to the directory specified by secure_file_priv, but it is still stuck

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

When loading a file(filename.csv) into the table, it gets trapped by the `---secure-file-priv option`, so I saved the file into the directory `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\` showed by the next command.

```
show variables like "secure_file_priv";
```

then,

```
load data infile 'C:\ProProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Ploads\losing\filmename.csv' into table tablename;
```

but it's still stuck with the `---secure-file-priv option`. Why is it still stuck?

Error code:

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 0):

\ is a escape literal.
so I needed to type
`C:\\ProgramData__MySQL\\MySQL...`